# CesiumJS selection handling is slow. How can I speed it up?

Tags: cesiumjs

I have a [Sandcastle Link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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) which demonstrates the problem.

I have many GeoJSON MultiPolygons. When this data is loaded into Cesium, each polygon becomes a separate entity. When I select, I need to:

1. set selected MultiPolygon entities to the selected color
2. set unselected MultiPolygon entities to the unselected color

Cesium then need to redraw.

The whole process taking 1 or 2 seconds. I am hoping it can be faster.

Is it possible to set the color of a group of entities?
What have I missed? Or, does this just take time?

Comment: To answer your first question, you are setting the color of a group of entities so I'm not sure what else you mean by that. I looked at your code and you're dealing with 5,000 entities and updating 100 of them each click. I don't know if there's a faster way because there isn't a lot of documentation on multipolygons in cesium. You may just want to use a smaller dataset. Hope this helps.

Comment: I mean setting the color once and having it apply to an entire group rather than needing to loop through and setting the color individually for each entity. Part of what is taking the time is the need to loop through and set those colors individually.

Comment: According to this [github ticket](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/issues/9431) it seems like a native multipolygon solution is not possible at the moment. There is however a tutorial that will create entity "folders" where you can add entities with a parent that you can show/hide the parent "folder" entity. Not the solution you're looking for but you may be able to play around with it some more. [cesium sandbox](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html?src=Show%20or%20Hide%20Entities.html)